# How do I select record from Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

i want to do a query statement on a Azure table storage.
Below the code I wrote :

```
    public List<T> RetrieveEntity<T>(string Query = null) where T : TableEntity, new()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the Table Query Object for Azure Table Storage  
            TableQuery<T> DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
            {
                DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(Query);
            }
           IEnumerable<T> IDataList = table.ExecuteQuery(DataTableQuery); 
            List<T> DataList = new List<T>();
            foreach (var singleData in IDataList)
                DataList.Add(singleData);
            return DataList;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }
```

How do I put in the following row ?

> > IEnumerable IDataList = table.ExecuteQuery(DataTableQuery);

in order to make all working?

Thanks,
Simone

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

Step 1. Get the query. Here's an example from [Writing LINQ queries against the Table service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/writing-linq-queries-against-the-table-service)

> ```
> var query = from entity in dataServiceContext.CreateQuery<SampleEntity>(tableName)  
>                  where entity.PartitionKey == "MyPartitionKey"  
>                  select new { entity.RowKey };
> ```

or

```
var partitionQuery = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition
                     ("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, myKey);
```

or

```
var startQ = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, start);
var endQ= TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, end);
var q = TableQuery.CombineFilters(startQ, TableOperators.And, endQ);
```

Step 2. Get the data

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDataAsync<T>(TableQuery<T> query)
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var queryResponse = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
        continuationToken = queryResponse.ContinuationToken;
        l.AddRange(queryResponse.Results);
    } 
    while (continuationToken != null);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: In my method shown above I replace **IEnumerable IDataList = table.ExecuteQuery(DataTableQuery)**;  with **IEnumerable<T> IDataList = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(DataTableQuery, null).Result as IEnumerable<T>** . Is it correct?